# Best function to use for Interpolation of tan function in Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have a set of data that is very similar to a tan function. I'm trying to use Scipy to interpolate value to use as a line of best fit to estimate values

Thanks

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information here.  `tan` does not produce a line.  If your data is close to `tan`, then why not just use `tan`?

Comment: Check https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html